# Why is the guestName prompt runs again?

Tags: javascript

can someone explain this to me? why is it prompt() running again?
And please give me some advice where and what should i change to have a better code. thank you.

```js
function welcomeGuest() {
  do {
    guestName = prompt("Welcome to my Anime Website! May I know your name?");
    if (guestName === null || guestName === false) {
      alert("Please come back again.");
      window.close();
    }
    if (guestName === "") {
      alert("Please enter your name!");
    } else if (guestName.length < 4) {
      alert("Your name should be atleast 4 characters!");
    } else if (!(isNaN(guestName))) {
      alert("Your name can't be number!");
    } else {
      guestNamesmall = guestName.slice(1, guestName.length);
      alert("Welcome to my Anime Website, " + guestName.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + guestNamesmall + "!");
      //bodyContent();
    }
  } while (guestName.length < 4 || !(isNaN(guestName)));

}

// EDIT: adding call to function for demo purposes
welcomeGuest();
```

**EDIT :** I'm sorry but my question is when I enter correct input(it should go to else statement, right?) but what happens to me is that the prompt is running again if else statement is met. Why is that?

Comment: It's inside a loop, so obviously it *can* run again (depending on how many times the loop executes). Do any of the alert messages display? What value are you entering into the prompt? As an aside, I know people with names that are less than four letters long.

Comment: The code shown seems to work as is. Are you sure your real code doesn't call the function more than once? Have you tried using your browser's debugger? I've edited your question just to wrap the existing code in a runnable snippet (so I added a call to your function, but did *not* modify your function except to reduce the indenting). When I run that, it does *not* keep prompting if I enter a value with at least four letters.

Comment: maybe its browser problem? tried it on jsfiddle it works fine. But in my google chrome after I entered a value with at least four letters it, the prompt appears again..

Comment: How do you call your function?

Comment: <html>
<head>
 <title>Anime Association Club</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="..\javascript\js\test.js"> </script>
 <style type"text/css" src="..\javascript\css\stylesheet.css"></style>
</head>
<body>
 <div class="main">
  <div id="headings">   
  </div>
  <div id="calendar"> 
  </div> 
  <script type="text/javascript">welcomeGuest()</script>
 </div>
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

if you call your welcomeGuest function only once and the condition inside your while loop is respected `guestName.length < 4 || !(isNaN(guestName))`it will not running again.

Comment: I'm sorry I revised my question

Answer (score 0):

The reason prompt is showing up again is because you have it in a loop until your condition is met. Therefore if `guestName.length < 4 || !(isNaN(guestName))` is never met, then it will continue to show.

I would avoid using a loop for something like this. You can use css to prevent a user from going through your site instead of continuously prompting them through a loop. Then use events to handle your logic. Do you have a submit/enter button? Then add your logic on the [click event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp). If not, then you can do it on the [key down event](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp) and look for the enter key.

for example:

```
var textbox = document.getElementById("idOfTextbox")
```

with option 1

```
textbox.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
//stop the click event from propagating
event.preventDefault();
//check if enter key was clicked (#13)
    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
        //do your logic to verify pass/fail of user input
    }
});
```

or option 2

```
textbox.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
//stop the click event from propagating
event.preventDefault();
//do your logic to verify pass/fail of user input
});
```

There are other events you may use, but I think these two would be the most beneficial in this situation.

Comment: I'm sorry I revised my question

Comment: Your code seems to work fine. Is there somewhere else you are unintentionally calling the function?